# Background image won't show in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Worked at this for hours and can't figure it out. Im just trying to get a background image to show in IE8. It works fine in Chrome & Firefox but won't show in IE8.

It's basically an iframe where I display web content but when the webpage loads or when you refresh the page, before you click a link in the nav, it's just a white box, and I'd like the white box to have the company logo in it.

I've tried multiple image formats (24bit, 8bit, JPG, PNG etc..) and multiple different images and nothing seems to render in IE8.

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<body>

<iframe allowtransparency="true" name="printer"></iframe>  

<style type="text/css">

iframe {
width: 84%;
height: 800px;
float: right;
background:transparent url(logoopac.png) no-repeat center;
} 

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: iframe supports html inside. I mean `<iframe><img src="foo.png"/></iframe>`. Why not try something like that?

Comment: If I put the image inside the iframe as suggested, it still doesnt display. Im left with the same white iframe box. It's as if the background of the iframe isnt transparent. The image might be there but it could be behind the iframe rather than showing through.

Comment: Then try something like: `<div><iframe></iframe></div>` and set the **background-image** to the **div**

Comment: unfortunately wrapping the iframe in the div and then adding the background image to the div has not worked either. Same white iframe box as before.

Comment: a last try: `<iframe allowtransparency="true" name="printer" src="logoopac.png"></iframe>`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but unfortunately it still wont work. If I add to the source to the iframe I get a 'webpage cannot be displayed' as if the iframe source only accepts web addresses.

Comment: Managed to find a solution!

Comment: Added src="javascript:'<body bgcolor=transparent>';" to the iframe element and this made the iframe transparent so I can now see the image that was sitting behind it all along! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great!!! Cool to hear that you found the solution!!!